# Testing Office Add-in in Powerpoint Online

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I uploaded the Office Addin to app catalog and published it and I am able to load the add-in in Word Online and Excel Online by going to `Insert -> Office Addins`.

In Powerpoint Online this option is missing from the Insert panel.Please refer to the screen shot below.
[image: Powerpoint Online Screenshot]

This is tested in both regular PowerPoint Online as well as the one from the Sharepoint menu.

So How can I load the office addin in PowerPoint online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the only way to use add-ins in PowerPoint Online is to insert them in another application (like PowerPoint for iPad or PowerPoint 2013/2016 for Windows) then open that document in PowerPoint Online, which works for content add-ins but not task pane ones.

At Microsoft we're currently working on adding the Insert Add-Ins button and adding task pane add-in support.

Comment: One of my Task Pane add-in got rejected by the store testing team, mentioning that it doesn't work in PowerPoint Online.Just wondering how they tested it !... Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Add-ins are now supported in PowerPoint Online, as well as Word Online and Excel Online. So you can use Insert > Office Add-ins to insert any add-ins you've already loaded into a catalog.

We also recently added the ability to side-load add-ins in the online clients, which is a really easy way to load in your add-ins while they're in development. Since you already have an app catalog, you may not need this feature, but it's worth mentioning nonetheless.

To side-load an add-in in Office Online, just click the Office Add-ins button on the Insert tab, and you will see a link in the upper-right corner of the dialog box to "Manage My Add-ins". That will open a drop-down menu with an option to Upload your add-in. (if you are using a work/school account, you will see a direct link to "Upload my Add-in".) You simply select your manifest file and it will load it into your browser's storage and open the add-in in Office. Remember to follow this procedure for other browsers or if your browser storage is cleared.

Hope this helps, thanks for the question!